# Jenkins pipeline fails to install dependencies for AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, jenkins, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have a Jenkins pipeline that uses AWS CDK to deploy a Lambda function to a test environment. I was able to deploy the Lambda function into test environment using `cdk deploy` and now I'm setting up the pipeline.

It seems that during the pipeline steps it fails to install the dependencies in the `package.json` file which causes this error :

```
+ npm run lint

> cdk@0.1.0 lint
> npm run lint --prefix LambdaFunctions


> report-lambda@1.0.0 lint
> eslint index.js

/tmp/lint-44ed690f.sh: 1: /tmp/lint-44ed690f.sh: eslint: not found
```

cdk package.json file :

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.106",
  "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
  "@types/node": "10.17.27",
  "@types/prettier": "2.6.0",
  "aws-cdk": "2.44.0",
  "aws-lambda": "^1.0.7",
  "jest": "^27.5.1",
  "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
  "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
  "typescript": "~3.9.7",
  "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
},
"dependencies": {
  "aws-cdk-lib": "2.44.0",
  "constructs": "^10.0.0",
  "source-map-support": "^0.5.21"
},
```

Lambda's package.json file :

```
"dependencies": {
  "moment": "^2.29.4",
  "ssh2-sftp-client": "^9.0.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "eslint": "^7.17.0",
  "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.3",
  "jest": "^26.6.3",
  "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
  "sonarqube-scanner": "^2.8.0"
},
```

Jenkins pipeline stage that it gets failed :

```
  stage('Build') {
    steps {
       sh 'npm install --unsafe-perm'
       sh 'npm run lint'
     }
   }
```

`npm run lint` command runs fine locally. Am I missing something here?
Or is there a way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: As I can see, first you need to install the dependencies for the Lambda function

Comment: @SándorBakos any idea how can I do that?

Comment: I thin in the `steps` go add an additional command, where you navigate into the Lambda Folder and run the npm install